# Multiple casper tests

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, casperjs

I have a question concerning multiple casper tests.
I am using [mocha-casper](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-casperjs) and I want to run multiple tests, one after another, without interfering with each other. I have a couple of test files, which are all working fine as long as I am executing them seperatly, but when I am trying to run them all at once I am getting the following error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:...`

I know that the problem is linked to the fact, that I am using `before(function () { casper.start(url)});` in every file and they somehow interfere with each other.

UPDATE:

I have tried the following things in order to sequence my test files:

- replaced `casper.start(url)` with `casper.reload()` to try to reset the page
- tried to only use `casper.start(url)` in the first test file and in the later ones I used `casper.thenOpen(url)`

But I still got the same problem!

Basically, the thing I want to do, is starting every test at the beginning of my view (single-page).

Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

Since I am programming in Ubuntu and running my test cases from command line, I have worked out the following workaround:
I added 
`|grep -v -e '^$' | grep -v "Unsafe JavaScript"` 
to my command